# Missing exponent in real number error in my expression

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am getting this error. Please suggest how to remove.

```
19 |    E = dsqrt(dcmplx((t1*t1 + t2*t2 + 2.d0*t1*t2*dcos(ek) - a*a),0.d0)
   |                                                                        1
Error: Missing exponent in real number at (1)
```

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. I suggest to check your parentheses. Be aware that instead of these specific functions it is much better to just call the generic  `cos`, `sqrt` and `cmplx` since Fortran 77.

Comment: We may need more code from you, see [mcve]. All variables you use should be declared.

Comment: You are missing a close bracket in your expression.  dsqrt does not take complex numbers.

Comment: What is the name of the file?  If it ends in .f, then you have fixed-form source code, which is limited to to 72 characters per line.  I suspect the `0)` is ignored.  To get shorter lines, you can use the generic function names `sqrt` and `cos` instead of `dsqrt` and `dcos`.  You can also simply multiple by `2` instead of `2.d0`, because Fortran understands mixed-mode arithmetic.

Comment: But there is nothing wrong with 2.0d0 - I personally avoid mixed-mode wherever possible as it seems to cause confusion, but it is a matter of style.

Comment: Never said that there was anything wrong with 2.0d0.   I just noted that if the line contains 74 characters and the code is fixed-form source code, then using 2 trims the line to 71 characters.

Comment: The name of the file ends with .f90

Comment: ! program for dispersion relation using function
 implicit real*8(a-h,o-z)
 parameter(N = 200) !NUmber of lattice sites
 real*8 t1, t2, ek , a
 complex*16 E
 integer :: b
 
 open (unit = 1,file = "c.dat")

 pi = 4.d0*datan(1.d0)
 del = 0.3d0

 t1 = 1.d0 + del
 t2 = 1.d0 - del
 a = 0.8d0


 do 
 m = 1 , N
 enddo
  do
  ek = -pi, pi, 2.d0 * pi * b / N
 

   E = dcmplx(dsqrt(t1*t1 + t2*t2 + 2.d0*t1*t2*dcos(ek) - a*a))
     *   ,0.d0)

 write(1,*) ek, real(E), dimag(E) , real(-E), dimag(-E)
        
 enddo

 stop
 end           THIS IS MY CODE

Comment: Please edit your original question and put the Fortran in it.  It is too painful to read otherwise.